# Qt connecting method in GUI class to slot in another class

Tags: c++, qt

I have a method in my `GUI` class that I would like to use as the signal to another method.

```
    Transition::void giveInputs(QString foldername,QString start, 
                               QString end,QString skipIndex){}
```

The slot has identical parameters, but is in the Worker class. How would I go about making the connection between these two? I know the second half will be:

```
...worker, SLOT(receiveInputs(QString foldername,QString start, 
                               QString end,QString skipIndex))
```

I have no idea how to set up the signal. Any advice or links to good resources would be appreciated.

This is how the Transition class is constructed. (From the default QtWidget formatting)

```
Transition::Transition(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Transition)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}
```

As far as I can tell, I can't just do Transition t* = new Transition later in the program.

Answer (score 2):

```
Transition *t = new Transition(...);
Worker *w = new Worker(...);
QObject::connect( t, SIGNAL( giveInputs(QString,QString,QString,QString)),
                        w, SLOT( giveInputs(QString,QString,QString,QString)));
```

If you are trying to create a connection from inside of the Transition class, then you'd use

```
QObject::connect( this, SIGNAL( giveInputs(QString,QString,QString,QString)),
                        w, SLOT( giveInputs(QString,QString,QString,QString)));
```

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/signalsandslots.html

Comment: Please see my edits for additional details about my troubles

Comment: @user3241316 what exactly is a problem at the moment?

Comment: Your solution seems like it would overwrite, or at least ignore, data that is already present.

Comment: what data? what will overwrite?

Comment: Is "this" in ui->setupUi(this);
an instance of the Transition class? That might be what I am trying to access

Comment: just write Transition *t = new Transition; or Transition *t = new Transition(some_qobject_ptr);

Comment: @user3241316 Yes, `this` would be an instance of the `Transition` class. If you are trying to create a connection from inside the `Transition` class, then you'd use `this`: `connect(this, SIGNAL(signal()), worker, SLOT(slot()));`.

Comment: @thuga I'm now having trouble making the actual connection. I have `emit(release(foldername,start,end,skipIndex));` in the end of a method that defines those 4 qstrings, qDebug shows that those 4 strings exist, but the program does not actually run any of the code in the SLOT. Setting the `connect` equal to a bool also shows that they are connected. What should I do to troubleshoot?

Comment: emit release(foldername,start,end,skipIndex); and check application output window - there might be info in case of connection failure, typo, etc